# any change in my init config delays emacs start by 90-150 seconds

Tags: init-file

weird issues. when i restart emacs it usually starts up pretty fast. BUT any small change i make to my config file makes emacs have a delay of 90-150 seconds each time. im using a org based config and this is what my init.el looks like

```
    ;;; init.el --- Where all the magic begins
;;
;; This file loads Org-mode and then loads the rest of our Emacs initialization from Emacs lisp
;; embedded in literate Org-mode files.
;; Load up Org Mode and (now included) Org Babel for elisp embedded in Org Mode files


(require 'package)

;since we are using use-package-don't autoload anythings
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)


(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
;; org maybe suspect of hanging melpa, if you have hangs disable this first
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/"))
;; Initialize installed package
(package-initialize)  

;; Bootstrap `use-package'
;(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
;  (package-refresh-contents)
;  (package-install 'use-package))

(require 'use-package)

;;; org babel magic happens here
(require 'org)
(org-babel-load-file
(expand-file-name "settings.org"
                   user-emacs-directory))

;; init.el ends here

(put 'dired-find-alternate-file 'disabled nil)
```

again after a successful emacs start i can kill it and quickly restart emacs but any change to my `setting.org` file (the actual config being tangles) creates this huge delay

i have tried binary partitioning of the settings.org file with no success which makes me think its not a conf issue

Edit: i will add that when i launch emacs from the CLI it seems to be stuck at the point where it says

```
│Warning: due to a long standing Gtk+ bug
│http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715
│Emacs might crash when run in daemon mode and the X11 connection is unexpectedly lo
│Using an Emacs configured with --with-x-toolkit=lucid does not have this problem.
```

that part halts for a good 2-3 minutes and then it dives into tangeling and i get all the messages like

`Wrote /home/zeltak/.emacs.d/settings.el`

any clue?

Comment: Is there anything suspicious in your message buffer?

Comment: You state that "any change to [your] `setting.org` file (the actual config being tangle[d]) causes this huge delay", yet you provided only the `init.el` file.  It is possible that your problem lies within `setting.org` and the particular change that you are implementing.

Comment: thx lawlist. i dont think so since its *any* change in any section. is there a more intelligent way to tackle this?

Comment: You can try to use the [Esup](https://github.com/jschaf/esup) package, that tries to do a sort of profile of your startup time and see where the time is consumed. I used it many times, even when is not perfect, it can get you a clue where the most time is consumed.

Comment: Actually, forget my previous comment, perhaps what happens it is that  when you load you org file for the first time it needs to tangle it on a new `.el` file? Thus, that's the extra time consumed. And the next times it simple don't need to tangle it (because there are not changes). Don't you think?

Comment: thx i dont think so (see edits of orig post above) since it halts for a good 2-3 minutes before outputting ``Wrote /home/zeltak/.emacs.d/settings.el 
``.  its crazy but even adding a single space in setting.org makes emacs delayed on startup.

Comment: any other input on this? really stuck here